# ¿Por qué los valores de la matriz no se muestran según lo estipulado?

Tags: array, c

Estoy tratando de mostrar los valores almacenados en una matriz 4x5 por filas y columnas, de manera separada. Sin embargo, las columnas me las imprime en el mismo orden que los valores almacenados en filas. Además, en los últimos valores arrojados no corresponden y son una hilera de números sin sentido. No sé si sea culpa de estar usando un compilador C online que no maneja correctamente tantos datos, porque solo en una de las ejecuciones me ha impreso correctamente los valores almacenados por columnas. ¿Qué sucede?

```
    #include <stdio.h> 
#define m 4 
#define n 5

int main () {

puts("Este programa almacenará los elementos de una matriz 4x5 y mostrará los valores de filas y columnas por separado.");

int matriz[m][n];
for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        printf("\nIntroduzca el elemento almacenado en la fila %d y columna %d: ", i+1, j+1);
        scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
    }
}

puts("\n\nElementos almacenados en las distintas filas de la matriz: ");

for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
    printf("\nFILA %d:", i+1);
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        printf(" %d", matriz[i][j]);
    }
}


puts("\n\nElementos almacenados en las distintas columnas de la matriz: ");

for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
    printf("\nCOLUMNA %d:", j+1);
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
        printf(" %d", matriz[j][i]);
    }
}
        
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Hola! Recuerda aceptar la respuesta correcta en tus preguntas anteriores (o indicar por qué no sirvieron).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que mezclas la forma de recorrer el array con la forma de pintarlo.

Es decir, tienes M filas, N columnas. Al alimentar la matriz, tienes la variable `i` que va hasta < M, `j` va hasta < N. Todo bien

Tu ejemplo tiene M=4 (0,1,2,3), N=5 (0,1,2,3,4).

Pintas por filas y todo bien.

```
FILA 1: 1 2 3 4 5
FILA 2: 6 7 8 9 0
FILA 3: 1 2 3 4 5
FILA 4: 6 7 8 9 0
```

LUEGO, vas a pintar por columnas. Iteras primero por N y luego por M. Bien. PERO le das índices invertidos a la matriz.

```
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        printf("\nCOLUMNA %d:", j+1);
        for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
            printf(" %d", matriz[j][i]);
        }
    }
```

Por ejemplo, en el caso frontera, `i=3, j=4`, vas a buscar la posición `matriz[4][3]` que no existe. Así pues, estás accediendo a posiciones de memoria que no son tuyas :P

Si inviertes la forma de recorrerlo PERO respetas los límites, vas a obtener lo que necesitas, creo

```
...
    puts("\n\nElementos almacenados en las distintas columnas de la matriz: ");
    
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        printf("\nCOLUMNA %d:", j+1);
        for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
            printf(" %d", matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
            
    return 0;
    }
```

La salida es

```
Elementos almacenados en las distintas columnas de la matriz: 

COLUMNA 1: 1 6 1 6
COLUMNA 2: 2 7 2 7
COLUMNA 3: 3 8 3 8
COLUMNA 4: 4 9 4 9
COLUMNA 5: 5 0 5 0
```